# Modifying form attributes

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm currently working with `form.attr` with jQuery and I have modified these to use the `iframe` upload however now the upload has completed I need to revert these changes back. Is there an easy way to do this? For example `form.revert()` or would I need to reset these using the `form.attr()` function?

The code i was using is:

```
var form = $('.myform');
form.attr("action", "scripts/old.php");
form.attr("method", "post");
form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
form.attr("target", "postiframe");
form.attr("file", $('#userfile').val());
```

but i now need to set it back to the original. I could use the above code again to reset but i would rather reset using a default method if possible

Comment: Please post your JS and HTML.

Comment: to reset i was resetting using the form.attr manually but i was asking if there is a way to reset it back to default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
document.getElementById("formID").reset();
```

On the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PabloWeb18/ykVuG/)

**Reference:** [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

Comment: although this is javascript you are right. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I'm glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean such code to make the form submit into an iframe?

```
var form = $("#form1");
form.attr("target", "MyFrame");
form.attr("action", "newpage.php");
form.submit();
```

In such case just store the original values as data values and revert right after submitting:

```
//get jQuery element:
var form = $("#form1");

//store original values:
form.data("original_target", form.attr("target"));
form.data("original_action", form.attr("action"));

//change values:
form.attr("target", "MyFrame");
form.attr("action", "newpage.php");

//submit:
form.submit();

//revert back to original:
form.attr("target", form.data("original_target"));
form.attr("action", form.data("original_action"));
```

And next submission will be in the main window, to original action page.

Comment: sorry i mean the default on the html is action="test.php" the form.attr("action","new") and then after form.submit(); reset back to the original method (before jquery intervention) to test.php